# Get xml with openoffice 3.3

Tags: xml, xsd, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I have a open office document. I want to get its xml. (Not save as word 2003 xml). I want to build up a xml from that. Does anybody know? (probably by making the zip from it?)(I have Windows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but the basic OpenOffice files are simply a set of zipped XML files.  If you change the file extention from odt (for a Write document) to .zip then you can easily unzip the structure and display all the separate files.  For example using a Write document the main file is content.xml although there are lots of other files that hold additional information such as styles.
Hope that is Helpful